# will not printf after signal interrupt handling when using with fgets

Tags: c, signals

I am now learning signal interrupt handling in C.  I find out that if I use `fgets()` after `printf()`, it works fine when no signal interrupt.  However if I press `Ctrl-C` once, it will not `printf("Ignore CTRL+C\n");` anymore.  It only read input.  May I ask why and how to solve it?

Thank you.

**Edit**

If I want to ignore `Ctrl-C`, how should I edit the code?   It does not `printf` after first `Ctrl-C` is pressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void signal_handler(int signum) {
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a[100];
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    while (1) {
        printf("Ignore CTRL+C\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(a, 100, stdin);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output I want**

```
Ignore CTRL+C
^C //take input here but I press CTRL-C, it goes to next line immediately without pressing ENTER
Ignore CTRL+C
a  //random input in fgets
Ignore CTEL+C
```

Comment: Cannot replicate with MSVC (using Windows `Sleep(1000)`). Aside: you didn't increment `count`, but my compilation exits on the *second* Ctrl-C anyway, without the message.

Comment: Cannot replicate with MacOS — catching multiple signals works fine.  Beware, though, that signal handling can be tricky.  Strictly speaking there are only limited things you're allowed to do in a signal handler, and `printf` isn't one of them.  (It usually works, though.)  Also, depending on the OS, unusual things may happen with the function that was interrupted, in this case `fgets` — it might seem to return an error, or even get stuck, which may be what you're seeing.

Comment: What OS are you using? You might try adding `clearerr(stdin)` somewhere in your loop.

Comment: I am using Linux

Comment: It is not safe to call `printf` in a signal handler.  Using a static variable inside a signal handler seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @WilliamPursell On the other hand, accessing a global variable (typically a flag of type `sig_atomic_t`) is pretty much the *only* thing you're really allowed to do in a signal handler, but a static variable is pretty much just like a global variable with local scope...

Comment: @yolopoi The `signal` function is said to be obsolete.  You might try `sigaction` instead (although it is indeed more complicated).  Another possibility (I'm grasping at straws here) would be to add a second call to `signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);` inside the signal handler, to re-catch it.  Once upon a time, you could only catch a signal once until you re-caught it again, and I think some latter-day `signal` implementations have reintroduced that antique functionality.  (There are subtleties here, concerning what should happen if a second one comes in while the first one is being handled.)

Comment: I tried to put ```signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);``` in ``` void signal_handler(int signum) ```, it needs to press ```ENTER``` to ```printf```.  Is there a way I do not need to press ```ENTER``` and it ```printf```?

Comment: suggest using `write()` function rather than `printf()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my machine and I had no problem with it.
Dont forget in order to read from stdin, you need to press `space`. If this didnt help, try to edit your question because the text is confusing.

I assumed `printf("Press CTRL+C 3 times to exit\n")` `was printf("Ignore CTRL+C\n");` on the code.

Comment: Is there any content in your ```void signal_handler ```?  Because if there is not content, it does not print ```Ignore CTRL+C\n ``` and just take ```fgets ```.  When I add ```signal(SIGINT, signal_handler); ``` in ```void signal_handler(int signum) ```, I need to press ```ENTER ``` to continue.  Is there a way I can have output like

Comment: ```Ignore CTRL+C``` ```(take input)``` ```^C(without pressing ENTER ``` ```Ignore CTRL +C ``` ```(take input)```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).